# Visual Studio 2008 x86 install on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-7, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

I am getting an error when the setup autorun executes.
It states that it is not compatible with the 64 bit operating system and does not allow me to install it. Is the VS installer 16 bit? The error also mentions this but I am not sure if it's true.

How can I by-pass this?

If I cannot, can some one suggest another VS that I should purchase? is there a 2008 (or higher) 64 bit version that I should run on windows 7?

Comment: Are you installing vs08 professional edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had any problems installing VS 2008 Team Suite on Windows 7 x64 RTM. You might have a [corrupt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/564a34f3-477c-4075-9aaf-af4d70140b12) installer. Also you may check if [this](http://jim.mcaleerblog.com/archives/212) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great help to you, but I am running Visual Studio 2008 Standard edition on Windows 7 64-bit without any issues. My installation was from an MSDN subscription media but it shouldn't make a difference.

There is no 64-bit version of Visual Studio 2008 currently.

There is someone here with a similar problem, you could try their [solution](http://jim.mcaleerblog.com/archives/212).

Comment: I am also having no problem running vs2008 in windows 7 64bit.